# Compare each column of one dataframe with another dataframe column and print each resulting overlap to separate files

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to compare each column of one dataframe with another dataframe column and print each resulting overlap to separate files.

I start with two test dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame("x" = c("a_b", "c_d", "e_f/c_f", "g_h"),
                  "y" = c(9,2,1,4),
                  "z" = c(7,5,8,5))
df2 <- data.frame("m" = c("c_f", "x_y"),
                  "n" = c("a_b", "x_y"))
```

and use a for loop to get the results.

```
for (i in colnames(df2)){ 
  ccc<-df1[grep(paste(df2[,i], collapse = "|"), df1$x), ]
  write.csv(ccc, file = paste(i, ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

Everything looks fine.

Now I am trying the same loop in my complete dataset (below are modified df1 and df2):

```
df1<- structure(list(BGC_Accession = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("BGC0000647", 
"BGC0000984"), class = "factor"), Genbank_ID = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("GCA_000202835", "GCA_000219295", "GCA_000964345", 
"GCA_003029685"), class = "factor"), BGC_Class = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("NRP/Polyketide", "Terpene"), class = "factor"), 
    BGC_Start = c(2093957L, 1L, 1L, 2656134L), BGC_End = c(2115021L, 
    4440L, 4186L, 2721658L), Product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Carotenoid", "Delftibactin"), class = "factor"), 
    Similarity = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "100%", class = "factor"), 
    Species_name = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Acidiphilium_multivorum", 
    "Acidiphilium_sp_PM", "Acidovorax_avenae/Acidovorax_avene", 
    "Acinetobacter_baumannii"), class = "factor"), Kingdom = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "k__Bacteria", class = "factor"), Phylum = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "p__Proteobacteria", class = "factor"), 
    Class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("c__Alphaproteobacteria", 
    "c__Betaproteobacteria"), class = "factor"), Order = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("o__Burkholderiales", "o__Rhodospirillales"
    ), class = "factor"), Family = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("f__Acetobacteraceae", "f__Comamonadaceae"), class = "factor"), 
    Genus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("g__Acidiphilium", 
    "g__Acidovorax"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("s__Acidiphilium_multivorum", "s__Acidiphilium_sp_PM", 
    "s__Acidovorax_avenae"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

```
df2<- structure(list(Gut_SRS011111 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Actinobaculum_unclassified"), class = "factor"), Gut_SRS011269 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Acidiphilium_multivorum", "Acinetobacter_baumannii", 
"Clostridium_citroniae"), class = "factor"), Gut_SRS011355 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Acidovorax_avene", "Streptococcus_gordonii"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Using the above script:

```
for (i in colnames(df2)){ 
  overlap_data<-df1[grep(paste(df2[,i], collapse = "|"), df1$Species_name), ]
  write.csv(overlap_data, file = paste(i, ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

It seems that only one of the three overlapping column (in df2) give proper result. 
For example, in the first column of df2, there is no overlap with df1 and it should give a blank result file. Second column output file looks ok. In the third file, I should get one overlap, not four as given in output file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Review your regex. This pattern, `""`, matches anything. Here's a MCVE for you to play with `grep("a|", letters)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the empty `""` cells, which should be `NA`.

```
df2[df2 == ""] <- NA
```

Now, the `grep` should work. I use `lapply` instead of `for` loop here:

```
invisible(lapply(names(df2), function(x) {
  rr <- df1[grep(paste0(df2[,x], collapse= "|"), df1$Species_name), ]
  write.csv(rr, file = paste(x, ".csv", sep=""))
}))
```

(The `invisible` avoids unnecessary and boring output to the console, you can also leave it out.)

Comment: Thanks you, but here the criteria of alternate match with '/' is missing. There should be one hit  for third column in df2.

Comment: @Bob You're right, that won't work so easily with `match`, `grep` is better. I think I found the issue, see update.

Comment: I see. You are right, problems are those empty cells. Thank you !

Comment: @Bob Yes, mostly it's better to encode something like that as `NA`.